# Python Pandas Accessing values from second index in multi-indexed dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I am not really sure how multi indexing works, so I maybe simply be trying to do the wrong things here. If I have a dataframe with

```
        Value
A  B         
1  1    5.67
1  2    6.87
1  3    7.23
2  1    8.67
2  2    9.87
2  3    10.23
```

If I want to access the elements where B=2, how would I do that? df.ix[2] gives me the A=2. To get a particular value it seems df.ix[(1,2)] but that is the purpose of the B index if you can't access it directly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
In [11]: df.xs(2, level='B')
Out[11]:
   Value
A
1   6.87
2   9.87
```

alternatively:

```
In [12]: df1.xs(1, level=1)
Out[12]:
   Value
A
1   5.67
2   8.67
```

Answer (score 6):

Just as an alternative, you could use `df.loc`:

```
>>> df.loc[(slice(None),2),:]
     Value
A B       
1 2   6.87
2 2   9.87
```

The tuple accesses the indexes in order. So, `slice(None)` grabs all values from index `'A'`, the second position limits based on the second level index, where `'B'=2` in this example. The `:` specifies that you want all columns, but you could subet the columns there as well.

Comment: you can even use a list of indices, like `df.loc[(slice(None),[2, 3]),:]`

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to return a cross-section, use [`xs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) (as mentioned by @Andy Hayden).

However, if you want to overwrite some values in the original dataframe, use [`pd.IndexSlice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html) (with [`pd.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)) instead. Given a dataframe `df`:

```
In [73]: df
Out[73]:
                 col_1  col_2
index_1 index_2
1       1            5      6
        1            5      6
        2            5      6
2       2            5      6
```

if you want to overwrite with `0` all elements in `col_1` where `index_2 == 2` do:

```
In [75]: df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 2], 'col_1'] = 0

In [76]: df
Out[76]:
                 col_1  col_2
index_1 index_2
1       1            5      6
        1            5      6
        2            0      6
2       2            0      6
```