# Pandas df, get row number using second index

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a multiindexed pandas df and need to find the row number of a specific index.
the Index is epoch time (Timestamp column) so several rows with the same index exist, I only need to find one of them.

df looks like this:

```
                  Temp1  Temp2 Uptime  CPULoadAvg1  CPULoadAvg5  CPULoadAvg15 GPUV1 GPUV2 GPUV3 GPUV4                  ts
Board Timestamp                                                                                                          
src   1689884603   30.6   34.0      0         0.08         0.02          0.01     0     0     0   100 2023-07-20 20:22:24
      1689884604   30.8   30.0      0         0.08         0.02          0.01     0     0     0   100 2023-07-20 20:22:24
      1689884605   30.7   31.0      0         0.15         0.03          0.01     0     0     0   100 2023-07-20 20:22:24
      1689884606   30.7   30.0      0         0.15         0.03          0.01     0     0     0   100 2023-07-20 20:22:24
      1689884607   30.5   30.0      0         0.15         0.03          0.01     0     0     0   100 2023-07-20 20:22:24
...                 ...    ...    ...          ...          ...           ...   ...   ...   ...   ...                 ...
coms  1690214970   47.1   53.0   2:59         2.12         2.06          2.06   689   641   876    64 2023-07-24 16:08:32
lr2   1690214970   34.3   49.0   2:59         0.31         0.13          0.04     0     0     0   100 2023-07-24 16:08:32
pp    1690214970   38.5   40.0    NaN          NaN          NaN           NaN     0     0     0   100 2023-07-24 16:08:32
srs   1690214970   43.0   49.0    NaN          NaN          NaN           NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN 2023-07-24 16:08:32
vel   1690214970   37.4   34.0    NaN          NaN          NaN           NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN 2023-07-24 16:08:32
```

EDIT:
So my task is to grab the last x minutes of the syslogs to graph the temperatures and other things. I filtered the syslog and made a df of the data. Ask the user for the number of minutes, and then have this code:

```
how_far_back_to_go_sec = (int(how_far_back_to_go_mins) * 60)
first_row_timestamp = int(df.index.levels[2][0])
last_row_timestamp = int(df.index.levels[2][-1])

timestamp_to_go_to = last_row_timestamp - how_far_back_to_go_sec      # Get desired Timestamp to start graph at

if timestamp_to_go_to < first_row_timestamp:
    print("Error: The logs to not go that far back. (",timestamp_to_go_to," seconds)")
    exit(1)  # Exit the code with an error code of 1

# try 1
df_xs = df.xs(timestamp_to_go_to, level='Timestamp')
print(df_xs)

# try 2
df_loc = df.loc[(slice(None), timestamp_to_go_to),:]
print(df_loc)
```

This returns a KeyError though. I have checked the df and timestamp_to_go_to is a valid index

---

added print(df.to_dict())
output:

```
'39', 'src', '1690216116'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'srs', '1690216116'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'vel', '1690216116'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'coms', '1690216117'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'loc', '1690216117'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'lr1', '1690216117'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'lr2', '1690216117'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'pp', '1690216117'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'src', '1690216117'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'srs', '1690216117'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'vel', '1690216117'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'coms', '1690216118'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'loc', '1690216118'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'lr1', '1690216118'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'lr2', '1690216118'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'pp', '1690216118'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'src', '1690216118'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'srs', '1690216118'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'vel', '1690216118'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'coms', '1690216119'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'loc', '1690216119'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'lr1', '1690216119'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'lr2', '1690216119'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'pp', '1690216119'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'src', '1690216119'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'srs', '1690216119'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'vel', '1690216119'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'coms', '1690216120'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'loc', '1690216120'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'lr1', '1690216120'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'lr2', '1690216120'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'pp', '1690216120'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'src', '1690216120'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'srs', '1690216120'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'vel', '1690216120'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'coms', '1690216121'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'loc', '1690216121'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'lr1', '1690216121'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'lr2', '1690216121'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'pp', '1690216121'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'src', '1690216121'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'srs', '1690216121'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'vel', '1690216121'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'coms', '1690216122'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'), ('39', 'loc', '1690216122'): Timestamp('2023-07-24 16:27:44'),
```

for that run the key was '1690216119' and still gave the keyError.

---

graphing code:

```
for idn, adfs in adfs.groupby(['Board'], level=0):
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=adfs.index.get_level_values('Timestamp').values,
                             y=adfs['Temp1'],
                             mode='lines+markers',  # Display both lines and markers
                             name=adfs.index.get_level_values('Board').values[0],
                             line=dict(width=1)))

fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(title="Time", tickformat='%H:%M:%S', type='date'),
                  yaxis=dict(title='Temperature (deg C)'),
                  title=figure_title)
# Show the plot
fig.show()
```

Comment: provide your data as Pandas df in code

Comment: What do you mean? The data is stored in a pandas df already

Comment: i mean provide your sample data as df code something like `df=pd.DataFram({'Temp1':[1,2,3], 'Temp2':[1,2,3]})` so it would be easier to reproduce it

Comment: oh, I dont have that. it is pulled from the syslog. I attached what print(df) and print(df.to_dict()) outputs thoguh

Comment: on the second thought , just do `df = df.reset_index()` and your df will be single indexed

Comment: I think I need it though to graph the plots correctly (added the graphing code). Need to graph all boards on one graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up doing a df.reset_index() to get rid of the multi indexing.
After that I looped through each row and searched for the epoch time value I wanted (none of the build in searches seemed to work). Once found I appended the rest of the rows to a new df

```
# single index way to cut down the df
rows_to_append = []
time_found = False
for row in adfs.itertuples(index=False):
    if int(row[1]) == timestamp_to_go_to:                   
        time_found = True
    if time_found:
        rows_to_append.append(row)
if not time_found:
    print("Log time not found, try going back to another point")
    exit(1) # Exit cause value not found

# After the loop, reset the index of the new DataFrame
adfs = pd.DataFrame(rows_to_append)
adfs.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
print(adfs)
```

Its not pretty, but it works.

Graphed it with:

```
for idn, adfs in adfs.groupby(['Board']):                                                       # single index
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
                            x=adfs['Timestamp'],                                                # single index
                             y=adfs['Temp1'],
                             mode='lines+markers',  # Display both lines and markers
                             name=adfs['Board'].values[0],                                      # single index
                             line=dict(width=1)))

fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(title="Time", tickformat='%H:%M:%S', tickmode='auto', nticks=20),
                  yaxis=dict(title='Temperature (deg C)'),
                  title=figure_title)
# Show the plot
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

This question can probably help accessing the second level of index [Python Pandas Accessing values from second index in multi-indexed dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744637/python-pandas-accessing-values-from-second-index-in-multi-indexed-dataframe)

Choices from the answers adapted to your dataframe:

```
df.xs(1690206352, level='Timestamp')

df.loc[(slice(None), 1690206352),:]
```

Although the concept of row number with complex indexes is a bit lost, I think. You can add an explicit row number column an search for its value for a certain timestamp like this:

```
df['row_number'] = range(df.shape[0])
df.xs(1690206352, level='Timestamp').min()['row_number']
```

Output:

```
5
```

You can also change `min()` to something more appropriate to your task to select only one row from multiple rows with timestamp 1690206352.

Comment: thanks for the responce, but .xs and .loc did not work; returned keyError. I added more info to my question.

Comment: Does something guarantee that `timestamp_to_go_to` is actually in the index? From your code snippet it doesn't look that way. Could you give an example of dataframe and `how_far_back_to_go_sec` value you're working with?

Comment: yes I do a simple check (just added it to the question). example key : 1690214850 which is in the df

Comment: It is still not obvious that timestamps go sequentially without any gaps, where your key can lend. Plus, your example key is not in the example df, so it's hard to check. Could you please provide an example that actually contains your key and causes errors and in `df.to_dict()` form rather than a table. That way everyone could reproduce your exact situation.

Comment: ok did that, confirmed agian that the key is in the df. still confused as to why its erroring. Does it matter the data type of the timestamp_to_go_to var? it's an int right now